Conditional Probability of a Specific Draw When Focusing on Red and Blue Balls
Question
An urn contains $r$ red balls, $b$ blue balls, and $g$ green balls. Balls are drawn sequentially without replacement. It is known that the last ball drawn was green. Considering only the sequence of red and blue balls among those drawn, what is the probability that the second ball (in this reduced sequence) is blue?
My Attempt
Assume as we are drawing out balls, we are also arranging them in a row.
The last green ball can be chosen in ${g \choose 1}$ ways. The remaining $(r+b+g-1)$ balls can be arranged in $(r+b+g-1)!$ ways.
Now among red and blue balls, the second ball can be fixed to be blue in ${b \choose 1}$ ways and the remaining red and blue balls can be arranged in $(r+b-1)!$ ways. Now we have to distribute the $g-1$ balls in $r+b+1$ places and also count their internal permutation and am stuck here.
Somehow it feels that this approach in not that elegant and there is no closed form answer of the part where I am stuck, that is, to distribute $n$ distinct objects into $r$ places where their internal ordering matters as well.

Each ball,  other than the last green,  is equally likely to be second.

From a comment-question left by the OP (i.e. original poster) following the answer of van der Wolf:

I understand the latter calculation but stuck in the first paragraph, how to "see" that the subsequence of the red-blue balls is completely independent of the green balls.

The assumption being made is one that comes naturally, after your intuition is stretched by exposure to many of these problems.  The response that I am giving provides a more formal approach.
For illustrative purposes, temporarily assume that # reds $= 3,~$ # blues $= 4,~$ 
and # greens $= 5,~$ and consider the following illustrative example:
r  g  g  b  r  r  g  g  b  b  b  g  :  Sequence-1

Ignoring the green balls gives

r  b  r  r  b  b  b                 :  Sequence-2


$\underline{\text{Sequence-1}}$
The number of different sequences, involving $~3~$ red, $~4~$ blue, and $~5~$ green is
$$\binom{12}{5} \times \binom{7}{3} \times \binom{4}{4} = \binom{12}{5} \times \binom{7}{3}.$$
When you assume that with the green balls ignored, that the second ball in the sequence is blue, you can express the number of favorable sequences as follows:
First of all, there are exactly $~\displaystyle \binom{12}{5}~$ ways of selecting which $~5~$ balls will be green.
Then, regardless of the selection made, there will then be $~7~$ remaining positions to fill.  If you then assume that the second of these $~7~$ positions is blue, you are left with $~6~$ remaining positions to fill, with $~3~$ red and $~3~$ blue remaining.
This can then be done in exactly $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{3}~$ ways.
Putting this all together, the probability that a sequence will be satisfying will be:
$$\left[ ~\binom{12}{5} \times \binom{6}{3} ~\right] \div \left[ ~\binom{12}{5} \times \binom{7}{3} ~\right] = \frac{4}{7}.$$

$\underline{\text{Sequence-2}}$
By analysis similar to the analysis in the previous section, the computation will be
$$\binom{6}{3} \div \binom{7}{3} = \frac{4}{7}.$$



In a similar fashion, in the more general case, where $~r, ~b, ~g~$ represents the number of reds, blues, and greens, respectively, then the two computations are
$$\left[ ~\binom{r + b + g}{g} \times \binom{r + b - 1}{r} ~\right] \div \left[ ~\binom{r + b + g}{g} \times \binom{r + b}{r} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{b}{r + b} \tag1 $$
and
$$\binom{r + b - 1}{r} \div \binom{r + b}{r} = \frac{b}{r + b}. \tag2 $$
Since the quotients in (1) and (2) above match, in the general case, the assumption that you can ignore the green balls is formally justified.

The subsequence of the red-blue balls is completely independent of the green balls; hence the probability is the same as if balls are drawn sequentially without replacement from an urn with just $r$ red and $b$ blue balls.
The probability that the second ball in this sequence is blue, by conditioning on the color of the first ball (red or blue) is
$$
\frac{r}{r+b}\times \frac{b}{r+b-1}+
\frac{b}{r+b}\times \frac{b-1}{r+b-1}=\frac{b}{r+b}
$$
(in fact the order of the balls does not matter).

I understand the latter calculation but stuck in the first paragraph, how to "see" that the subsequence of the red-blue balls is completely independent of the green balls.

@Debu I wrote a (formal) second answer, to respond to your comment-question.
